# Use a method inside another class Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hello guys I'm new in Java and Android and I need your help please.
I have to use a method inside another class but it doesn't work, it says that it can't find my canvas parameters inside my onDraw method in the Game class.
How can I fix it ?
Here is the code for you to understand the situation better :

This my **Draw** class where the **onDraw** method is :

```
public class Draw extends View {
    public Draw(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Rect rect = new Rect();
        rect.set(0,0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()/2 );
        Paint blue = new Paint();
        blue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        blue.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawRect(rect,blue);
    }

}
```

And here is my **Game** class where I want to use the **onDraw** method :

```
public class Game extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Draw draw;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        Canvas canvas;
        draw.onDraw(canvas);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error please?

Comment: cannot resolve symbol 'canvas'

Comment: your Draw and Canvas are null.
you have to initialize them first

Comment: @Matnako on what line?

Comment: @Mureinik on the last line of the Game class

Comment: and @OhadShiffer How to initialize it ? What I did haven't worked

Comment: draw = new Draw(this);     
canvas = new Canvas()

Comment: It compiles but nothing appears on the screen ^^
Any idea ?

Comment: This seems all wrong to me.  onDraw is not meant to be called in your code.  Android calls it when it's time for the View to render itself, after it's been added to the view hierarchy.

Comment: @DougStevenson What can I do to fix it then ? :)

Comment: There's no "fix".  I suggest you learn about how to correctly create custom views for Android apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your **Game** Class as follows:

```
public class Game extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new Draw(this));  //change on this line

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want use another class you must create new Object from class first .
like this for generating new object from your class :

```
public class Game extends AppCompatActivity {

Draw my_draw;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    //Generate new object from class
    my_draw = new Draw(Game.this);
    Canvas canvas;
    my_draw.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Comment: It works only if i initialize the canvas out of the onCreate method but it says suspicious method call and it doesn't create my rectangle :(
What can I do ?

Comment: i don't know about your code but i wrote base law of using a class and it's methods in another class